# I am trying destructuring assignment in JavaScript but its giving undefined

Tags: javascript, object, object-destructuring

```js
const myObj = {
    name: "Rahul",
    age: 34,
    Roll: 23
}
// console.log(myObj)

const {x, y, z} = myObj;
console.log(x)
```

I tried to store values of myObj in these three variables using the destructuring assignment but its giving undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You use destructuring assignment this way:

```
const myObj = { name: "Rahul", age: 34, Roll: 23 }
const {name, age, Roll} = myObj;
```

but if you want to rename the variables with `x`, `y` and `z` you can do this:

```
const myObj = { name: "Rahul", age: 34, Roll: 23 }
const {name: x, age: y, Roll: y} = myObj;
```

[Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment?retiredLocale=he)

Answer (score 0):

you can destructure something like this

```
const {name:x, age:y, Roll:x } = myObj;
```

You are trying to access x,y and z which are not the properties of your object